# what does "-&gt;" mean in swift when declaring functions?

Tags: ios, swift, function-declaration

example function

```
func example(titles: [String]) `-&gt;` [UIButton] {

}
```

and where could i find more docs on this topic (docs relevant to functions declaring in swift)?

Comment: ``gt`` means "greater than", and ``&gt;`` in an escaped form of ">"

Comment: `&gt;` means `>`, altogether it is `->`.

Comment: -&gt; represent the -> mark. And &quot; represent the single " quote.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no `&gt;` in swift function declarations - someone botched up the HTML rendering in the page you were reading. It was supposed to be `->` (an arrow made up of a hypen and the greater than operator) that's used to denote the return type of the function.

The text was supposed to read

```
func example(titles: [String]) -> [UIButton] {

}
```

Which means the `example` function has one parameter called `titles` of type `[String]` (array of String) and it returns a `[UIButton]` (array of UIButton).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're talking about `->` the portion after that denotes the return value of the function.